# Europe: big fly with black/yellow striped body: I'm guessing a horse fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This one made a summer night visit to the room and tried to escape by banging against the ceiling. What is it? I found nothing which corresponds, though "horse fly" might be a close match.

- Location: Central Europe, [Luxembourg](https://www.google.lu/maps/@49.91,7.08,720000m/data=!3m1!1e3)
- Locality: Where the suburb morphs into the not-yet-conquered countryside
- Time: Late August, Nighttime
- Weather: Quite warm (~27°C). Dry.

Here is an MP4 of the beast: https://i.imgur.com/F5yqMQ8.mp4

It is about 2 cm (0.8 inch) large. Relatively plump, keels over and likes to clean itself a lot.

[image: unknown fly 1]

Large head, large eyes, a bit hairy, two black stripes

[image: unknown fly 2]

Once it falls on its back it wallows a bit, there is clearly a probabilistic algorithm to get itself out of the predicament:

[image: unknown fly, wallowing]

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks Bryan. I have added some info. And a link to an MP4

Comment: Its not a horsefly (Tabanidae), but rather, a flower fly (Syrphidae). I don't know what species.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, because of the size and shape, I thought that it was a horsefly, but no horsefly looks like that (at least not in Luxembourg). It turns out that it was a hoverfly, just as Karl Kjer said. The species is *Volucella zonaria*, or the hornet mimic hoverfly. This hoverfly lives in most of Europe (including Luxembourg) and is [15-25 mm](https://books.google.com/books?id=pDRuBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT172&lpg=PT172&dq=volucella%20zonaria&source=bl&ots=-FqTzMYRVS&sig=ACfU3U31ohw19CykT6hfbHExSNvmQshV-A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ7Z_UwtDpAhXEKs0KHUdrC7sQ6AEwCHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=volucella%20zonaria%20&f=false) in length, consistent with your 20 mm estimate.

In this image you can see the same coloration and abdominal markings as your insect.

[image]

The markings in your photo are very difficult to see but are there.

[image]

[image]

[Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volucella_zonaria)

[original image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Volucella_September_2007-2.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten about that question. Good id.